# Database view: compare values and group by date

Tags: mysql, view

I have a database table containing information about badminton sets played. The structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUtYP.jpg).

I want to create a db view, based on this table, with three columns:

- Gameday
- Number of sets won by P1 (where P1 score > P2 score)
- Number of sets won by P2 (where P2 score > P1 score)

It should be grouped by gameday, so that there is one row per gameday. I need some MySQL help on how to construct the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `Sub query` and `Group by`.

```
select gameday, 
(select count(set_id) from table_name where player_one_score > player_one_score where gameday = t.gameday) as p1_won,
(select count(set_id) from table_name where player_one_score < player_one_score where gameday = t.gameday) as p2_won
from table_name as t
group by gameday
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue, after I fixed a few things: player_two_score should be in the conditions, and the "where [...] where" was replaced by "where [...] AND".